# What design pattern is appropriate here?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I am working on an application which has REST endpoints and for a Get-By-ID service, I am populating a resource (basically a POJO) by collecting data from the persistent store. Now, before sending the response back, I have to populate the HREF in the POJO resource. I want to do it in a generic way so that various other REST services (search etc.) can use it. I want to do this HREF population at a common place for reusability purpose. In a nutshell, my resource POJO can go through various massaging layers to have different state changed and finally sent back to the consumer.

```
    Resource POJO --> Massager 1 --> Massager 2 --> Final Massaged POJO
```

Could someone help me to figure out a design pattern that can fit my problem.

I thought of Decorator pattern, but somehow it does not sail my ship.

~ NN

Comment: How about chain of resposibility pattern?

Comment: According to creating the HREFS as reference to other objects: that should be implemented by the REST-framework you are using. In a web-app you woudn't care about link-generation either...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could adapt [Chain Of Responsability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern#Java) to your needs. Instead of having a series of processing objects which pass your POJO from one to another in case it cannot handle it, you could process your POJO and then pass it further.

```
abstract class Messager{

    private  Messager nextMessager;

    void setNextMessager(Messager messager){
        this.nextMessager = messager;
    }

    Messager getNextMessager(){
        return this.nextMessager;
    }

    abstract void handle(Pojo pojo);
}

class FooMessager extends Messager{

    void handle(Pojo pojo){
       //operate on your pojo
       if(pojo.getHref == null){
           pojo.setHref("broken");
       }

       if(this.getNextMessager() != null){
           this.getNextMessager().handle(pojo);
       }

    }
}

class BarMessager{

     void handle(Pojo pojo){
       //operate on your pojo
       if(pojo.getHref().contains("broken")){
          pojo.setHref(pojo.getHref().replace("broken","fixed"));
       }

       if(this.getNextMessager() != null){
           this.getNextMessager().handle(pojo);
       }

    }

}

class Pojo{

    private String href;

    public Pojo() {
    }

    public String getHref() {
        return href;
    }

    public void setHref(String href) {
        this.href = href;
    }

}

class Test{

     public static void main(String[] args) {

         Pojo pojo = new Pojo();
         pojo.setHref(null);

         Messager foo = new FooMessager();
         Messager bar = new BarMessager();
         foo.setNextMessager(bar);

         foo.handle();
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel for the example code. I believe this pattern can help me for my problem and I am going with this.

Answer (score 1):

Even if the previous answers are good and does solve it, I want to propose you additional way if you want to go further. The communication between objects is very common, so a lot of concepts are out there and you can choose the one that fits best for your needs.

The [Command pattern](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077569/core-java/java-tip-68--learn-how-to-implement-the-command-pattern-in-java.html) can help you with the encapsulation of a request as an object in

> collecting data from the persistent store

It'll allow you to parameterize clients with queue or log requests.

The [Mediator pattern](http://www.journaldev.com/1730/mediator-design-pattern-in-java-example-tutorial) can define your communication between the `Massager 1 --> Massager 2` classes. By doing this it'll encapsulate your objects interaction. Also it promotes loose coupling by keeping objects from referring to each other explicitly, and it'll let you vary their interaction independently.

If you'll deal with how to notify change to `Massager 1 --> Massager 2` classes

> my resource POJO can go through various massaging layers to have different state changed

than the [Observer pattern](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/observer_pattern.htm) can define a dependency between your objects so that when one object changes state, all its dependents are notified and updated automatically.

Comment: Thank you very much; these are very nice ideas and we already have implemented quite a few patterns within our app. For my problem as others suggested I am going with Chain of Responsibility pattern.